# Java HashMap key value storage and retrieval

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to store values and retrieve them from a Java HashMap.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void processHashMap()
{
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put(1,"godric gryfindor");
    hm.put(2,"helga hufflepuff"); 
    hm.put(3,"rowena ravenclaw");
    hm.put(4,"salazaar slytherin");
}
```

I want to retrieve all Keys and Values from the HashMap as a Java Collection or utility set (for example `LinkedList`).

I know I can get the value if I know the key, like this:

```
hm.get(1);
```

Is there a way to retrieve key values as a list?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Java Hashmap key value example:**

```
public void processHashMap() {
    //add keys->value pairs to a hashmap:
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put(1, "godric gryfindor");
    hm.put(2, "helga hufflepuff");
    hm.put(3, "rowena ravenclaw");
    hm.put(4, "salazaar slytherin");

    //Then get data back out of it:
    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
    Iterator itr = hm.keySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        String key = itr.next();
        ll.add(key);
    }

    System.out.print(ll);  //The key list will be printed.
}
```

Answer (score 37):

I use these three ways to iterate a map. All methods ([`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29), [`values`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), [`entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)) return a collection.

```
// Given the following map
Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> myMap;

// Iterate all keys
for (KeyClass key  : myMap.keySet()) 
    System.out.println(key);

// Iterate all values
for (ValueClass value  : myMap.values()) 
    System.out.println(value);

// Iterate all key/value pairs
for (Entry<KeyClass, ValueClass> entry  : myMap.entrySet()) 
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
```

Since Java 8 i often use [`Stream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) with [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
    // Iterate all keys
    myMap.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> System.out.println(key));

    // Iterate all values
    myMap.values().parallelStream().forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));

    // Iterate all key/value pairs
    myMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 10):

[`map.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) would give you all the keys

Comment: thanks for ur reply  bro.....so is it possible for me to typecast the return value into a LinkedList........??

Comment: returned value is one of the type of `Set`, so not directly but you can construct from it

Answer (score 3):

```
//import statements
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

// hashmap test class
public class HashMapTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Integer,String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>(); 

        hashMap.put(91, "India");
        hashMap.put(34, "Spain");
        hashMap.put(63, "Philippines");
        hashMap.put(41, "Switzerland");

        // sorting elements
        System.out.println("Unsorted HashMap: " + hashMap);
        TreeMap<Integer,String> sortedHashMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>(hashMap);
        System.out.println("Sorted HashMap: " + sortedHashMap);

        // hashmap empty check
        boolean isHashMapEmpty = hashMap.isEmpty();
        System.out.println("HashMap Empty: " + isHashMapEmpty);

        // hashmap size
        System.out.println("HashMap Size: " + hashMap.size());

        // hashmap iteration and printing
        Iterator<Integer> keyIterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = keyIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Code=" + key + "  Country=" + hashMap.get(key));
        }

        // searching element by key and value
        System.out.println("Does HashMap contains 91 as key: " + hashMap.containsKey(91));
        System.out.println("Does HashMap contains India as value: " + hashMap.containsValue("India"));

        // deleting element by key
        Integer key = 91;
        Object value = hashMap.remove(key);
        System.out.println("Following item is removed from HashMap: " + value);

    }

}
```

Comment: A complete example on basic operations of HashMap

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keySet()` to retrieve the keys.
You should also consider adding typing in your Map, e.g :

```
Map<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
hm.put(1,"godric gryfindor");
hm.put(2,"helga hufflepuff"); 
hm.put(3,"rowena ravenclaw");
hm.put(4,"salazaar slytherin");

Set<Integer> keys = hm.keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void hashMapExample(){

    HashMap<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hMap.put("key1", "val1");
    hMap.put("key2", "val2");
    hMap.put("key3", "val3");
    hMap.put("key4", "val4");
    hMap.put("key5", "val5");

    if(hMap != null && !hMap.isEmpty()){
        for(String key : hMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key+":"+hMap.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up