# Android - Is it possible to have a lookup array?

Tags: android, arrays

I know there's an answer to this, but i'm not sure what to search and cannot remember the right phrasing.

Essentially what i mean, i'm being passed an integer. I want to search through an array using this integer to return a string value.

E.g.

I'm given the number 2. My lookup array looks like so:

```
array.add(1, "Auckland")
array.add(2, "Wellington")
array.add(3, "Bay of Plenty")
```

When i iterate through the array, i want to return "Wellington".

Can someone point me in the right direction please? :)

Comment: are your numbers always sequential like that? If so why not just look up by index? If the numbers are unique maybe try a [Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048783/java-hashmap-key-value-storage-and-retrieval)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you should declare a HashMap of Integer String:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map= new HashMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(1, "Auckland");
map.put(2, "Wellington");
map.put(3, "Bay of Plenty");
```

And then to get the String you should call the HashMap using the key:

```
String yourString = map.get(1);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for :)